# Android navigation drawer with a single collapsing item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using a custom navigation drawer in my application.
The layout is a custom one.

I have customed the layout this way,

http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

I have used this link to use the code.

But going forward, I have to customize it more this way, a particular item should have a collapsing tray,
something like this[image: This app, has a particular item with a collapsing tray]

And my req. is also the same, a particular item should be collapsable, 
[image: This is what I want to acheive]

Answer (score 0):

Check this [DrawerLayoutTest](https://github.com/PrashamTrivedi/DrawerLayoutTest) on github, it will let you collapse items in navigation drawer.

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I do not want my CustomAdapter to extend  BaseExpandableListAdapter.
Is there any other way known to you, by using the BaseAdapter itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need either to implement it yourself or use third-party library, like [SlideExpandableListView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/253)

Comment: Not quite happy with the library implementation